# Go about listening to a event using eventemitter

Tags: node.js, eventemitter

I'm still quite new to NodeJS and I'm trying to figure out how to use EventEmitter properly I've read this [article](https://appdividend.com/2017/10/16/node-js-events-eventemitter-tutorial-example-scratch/) I saw that every event registered uses `emitter.emit('listenrName', ...)`

I'm currently using this library [Library](https://github.com/SzymonLisowiec/node-epicgames-client/blob/master/src/Communicator/index.js)

and there are events in that class without a emitter.emit method so I have absolutely no clue how I would listen for example "sendMessage" when "SendMessage" has no emitter.emit method.

This is what I came up with so far not sure what else I should do or if I'm doing it the wrong way.

```
communicator.on('sendMessage', async(to, message) => {

});
```

Comment: The class you have linked to does not use an event for sending messages, it simply has a `sendMessage` method. So just call that on your class instance. No listener business involved.

Comment: Worked. Thanks.